# Subscript out of bounds error in R

Tags: r, subscript

My simple code is:

```
library(kernlab)
zoo <- matrix(sample(1:10, 240*7200, replace = TRUE), 240, 7200)
mx=data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow =30))
mx[1,1]=0
mx[1,2]=1
m=0
mm=1
for (i in 1:30){
  m=m+length(zoo[,1])
  mx[i+1,1]=m
  mm=mm+length(zoo[,1])
  mx[i+1,2]=mm
}
```

Above code is first part to create `mx`.

```
ram=data.frame(matrix(ncol = 30, nrow = length(zoo[,1])))
for (i in 1:30){
  A<-zoo[,c(mx[i,2]:mx[i,1]+length(zoo[,1]))]
  sc <- specc(A,data=kernelMatrix,centers=2)
  ram[,i]=data.matrix(sc@.Data)
}
```

This parts gives

```
Error in zoo[, c(mx[i, 2]:mx[i, 1] + length(zoo[, 1]))] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

if I run it from `i in 1:29`, there is no error. Thus the problem is in `i=30`. However, if I manually plug values of `mx[30,2]` and `mx[30,1]`, again there is no error. I did not understand the problem and could not solve. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Note: `dim(zoo)=240 7200`

Note: `A<-zoo[,c(mx[30,2]:mx[30,1]+length(zoo[,1]))]` gives same error. mx[30,2]= 6961 mx[30,1]=7200. Then `A<-zoo[,c(6961:7200)]` works without error.

Comment: Typo when I post the question, I fixed it.

Comment: zoo is file I loaded it. it is 240x7200 Matrix without missing values.

Comment: for `i = 30`, `c(mx[i,2]:mx[i,1]+length(zoo[,1]))` gives `7201 7200`.

Comment: but `mx[30,2]=6961` and `mx[30,2]=6960` rightt? I could not figure it out.

Comment: Yes, but `length(zoo[,1])` is `240`. `6961:6960+240` gives `7201 7200`

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks a lot @Pascal

Comment: You need brackets at the right place: `c(mx[i,2]:(mx[i,1]+length(zoo[,1])))`